# Why doesn't it remove this unicode character?

Tags: python

```
JUNK_PATTERN = re.compile(r"[●~〜╮╯▽╰╭★→…&*^❤～\u200b]")
text = 'test <200b><200b>'
print(len(text), text)
text = remove_junk(text)
print(len(text), text)

def remove_junk(text):
    return re.sub(JUNK_PATTERN, "", text).strip()
```

The output is:

```
17 test <200b><200b>
17 test <200b><200b>
```

Why isn't the <200b> not removed by the re?

Comment: Please share the `remove_junk` function, make it so we can replicate the enitre process

Comment: `\u200b` in your regular expression is one character, a zero-width space. It will not match the characters `2`, `0` or `b`.

Comment: `<200b>` is not a Unicode character. It's 6 characters, `<`, `2`, `0`, `0`, `b`, and `>`.

Answer (score 1):

You should un-escape unicode encoded chars like `<200b>`, converting them to real 1-char unicode sequence. Full corrected code down below:

```
import re

JUNK_PATTERN = re.compile(r"[●~〜╮╯▽╰╭★→…&*^❤～\u200b]")

def remove_junk(text):
    return re.sub(JUNK_PATTERN, "", text).strip()
    
def unescape_uni_codes(text):
    for m in reversed(list(re.finditer(r'<[a-fA-F\d]{4}>', text))):
        s = m.span()
        text = text[:s[0]] + bytes().fromhex(m.group(0)[1:-1]).decode('utf-16-be') + text[s[1]:]
    return text

text = 'test <200b> <200c>'

print(len(text), text)
text = unescape_uni_codes(text)
print(len(text), text)
text = remove_junk(text)
print(len(text), text)
```

Comment: What about if I simply do 'text = text.replace('<200b>', '')'? I am wondering why people use <200b> instead of the standard \u200b in docs?

Comment: @marlon I just solved the case of questioner's task where all changes to be made are specified as one single long regex. Of cause if they're in a form of non-regex string pairs `(from, to)` then we can just do `for from, to in changes: text = text.replace(from, to)`, but initial task was to use regex.